# How to retrieve an IPV6 knowing the IPV4?

Tags: nmap, ipv6

I'm using **nmap** to scan a training lab environment, and I would like to check if a remote machine has an IPV6 address. I only know the IPV4 of the machine. 
And I know that scanning through IPV6 would give me much informations about the target, but I don't know how to retrieve it (**nmap** won't help me with it).

p.s: I don't know if it's the good place to post this question, so if you know a better place please tell me.

Cheers

Comment: The two are not related.  An IPv4 address tells you nothing about an IPv6 address.

Comment: Unfortunately, this really isn't a security question. I'm not sure where to migrate this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not an IPv6 equivalent for every IPv4 address. They are completely independent addressing schemes.

They also can be configured totally differently, even for the same ISP or for the same device.

You would need cooperation from the device in question to find out a) if it uses IPv6, and b) what the IPv6 address is. Still that might be subject to change though.